# How does Parity pendingTransactionsStats works?

Tags: parity, pending-transactions

I am trying to develop little method to track status of my pending transactions by given address together with propagation info. But I am bit confused about `pendingTransactionsStats` behavior as it changes each time i check.

My code first check for `pendingTransactions` of my address then checks `pendingTransactionsStats` for hashes that retrieved from `pendingTransactions`.

```
var myAddr =  "0x2c5253b9055cfd3ac7a2d352934fb5c45f667367";
api.parity.pendingTransactions()
  .then((pendingTransactions)=>{

    // filter my transaction by my address
    let pendingQueue = _.filter(pendingTransactions, (a) =>  {return a.from.toLowerCase() == myAddr});   
    if(pendingQueue.length > 0) {

      // get stats of my pending transactions
      api.parity.pendingTransactionsStats().then((pendingTransactionsStats)=>{
        for (var i = 0, l = pendingQueue.length; i < l; i++) { 
          let pendingHash = pendingQueue[i].hash;
          console.log("pendingHash : " , pendingQueue[i].hash);
          console.log(pendingTransactionsStats[pendingHash]);
        }

      });
    } else {
      console.log("no pending transactions");
    }
  });
```

`pendingTransactionsStats` gives different propogation info each time i check. Sometimes doesnt even return anything. Is it expected behaviour? If yes, what should i understand from this. My aim is to be sure that my pending transaction is propagated to network. So i can be sure that reason of pending is not about network but only gasPrice.

My code outputs with few seconds inbetween :

```
pendingHash :  0x551e1af7c403c7fc847ecc2c4b8174e0853931f07fbc0eefd267a68fd87604e3
{ firstSeen: 3609956,
  propagatedTo: 
   { '0xd1da0fa61e0f1b69918ad330e59a12eddd1450256dd6837764c1d587b1adb5cf8ef661c043588f61ec0603e73fc641f5855ef486990ce13021d019e7a3c15de7': 1 } }
```

After few seconds no stats found:

```
pendingHash :  0x551e1af7c403c7fc847ecc2c4b8174e0853931f07fbc0eefd267a68fd87604e3
undefined
```

Then some more seconds and there two nodes :

```
{ firstSeen: 3609957,
  propagatedTo: 
   { '0x3b1dcc486de0b4b0cd2783b5fd770e183b0f063cd045b775e330aa8a3059ebff3d65131fa6f51761bef1152c54cfd9dd83b71aed38e9c1aaeb5660c8b73d5daa': 1,
     '0xf2170f44de933a592b6bac04f4926a81b7eae662abf888719e55a6556dd3dfbfa9ca36f314bc079d0ae2932fde27adee634363170d0316eb5a28e9baacca1868': 1 } }
```

One more question; what do those numbers indicate with peer Ids?